# Strange solutions using Finite Element Analysis

Tags: finite-element, computational-physics, numerical-modelling

I've implemented the Finite Element Method to model the heat transfer between two different materials where one material is surrounded by the other.

When I run the model I'm getting some strange results. Whenever I run the model, I get what appears to be a sinc function through space and a linear change through time. My gut has been telling me that a part of my implementation isn't right but I haven't been able to figure out what is going on. The positional axis is the position of each individual element, not the radial distance.
[image: Surf plot of the generated model solution]

The model that I'm currently using is a one dimensional model over the radius of a cylinder with heat being generated within the submerged material and the solution is trying to solve how heat moves through the whole system. Due to symmetry in the system and ignoring how heat moves through the length of the cylinder, I'm modelling the elements as a series of concentric circles with a known thickness. Thinking maybe it was a problem with how I implemented the model, I implemented a two dimensional model looking at a small square to get a proof of concept and I found a similar result in the spatial dimensions.

The 1 dimensional problem I'm solving is 
$$\rho c_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)$$

The domain can be seen in the picture below. The inner radius has the set of parameters defined as $k_1, \rho_1, c_{p1}$ and the outer radius has the set of parameters defined as $k_2, \rho_2, c_{p2}$. The inner material is much smaller than the outer material, such that the image is not to scale. 
[image: domain of the model, not to scale]

The only boundary condition that I care about is the boundary between the two materials as I'm assuming the two materials are at the same temperature and the outer radius is insulated
$$k_1 \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}|_{r=R_1} = k_2 \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}|_{r=R_1}$$

The source term I'm using is a constant $Q$ and only being applied to the elements in the smaller radius once I get the model working properly I'll refine the source term some more. The large spike in the middle of the first image is the elements caused by the heat source - currently using two elements for now once I'll add more once things work.

I have no formal training with the Finite Element Model and the only understanding I have is from reading numerous books and papers I've scrounged through trying to understand the model, so the problem I'm experiencing could be a simple oversight on my part or a pitfall that I've known nothing about. If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to solve this problem I would be grateful.

Comment: What is the (mathematical) problem that you are solving? What is the domain (a drawing might help)? What are the boundary conditions and source terms (if any)?

Comment: I've added comments, let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: There really isn't enough information in even your updated post to say anything definitive. However, your intuition is correct: your numerical results are wrong. Second, one of the major strengths of FEM is that no special treatment is required at discontinuous material interfaces; so if you are doing something to enforce the BC you show above, that is also incorrect. Beyond that, if this is your first FEM implementation, you might start with a slightly simpler version-- 1D but not axi-symmetric and a single material. You can find *many* implementations of this on the web.

Comment: This isn't my first FEM implementation. I've started out doing steady-state models before slowly building up my understanding before to transient models. I've followed the examples and the relevant questions in 'A First Course in the Finite Element Method' by Logan before moving onto more complicated models.

The treatment I give to the boundary condition is that I treat it like there was no interface and the interfaces are separated by a node. This is why I'm using FEM rather than FDM.

I'm going to re-visit the earlier work I've done to see if I didn't miss something.

Comment: I think that is more common to have a continuous field between two materials than having their derivatives continuous. Although I don't see that easy your internal boundary condition, contrary to what @BillGreene mentioned. As a side question, have you solved this problem in the steady state case?

Comment: Your model is a parabolic PDE. It requires only 2 boundary conditions. One in $r=0$ (zerogradient of temperature) and the other at $r=R_{outer}$ (imposed temperature or imposed heat flux). If you are solving 2 coupled problems (inner cylinder and outer one) you can put the interface BC on heat fluxes as you did. Otherwide you must solve for the case I said.